# Real Exchange Rate (Euro/Sterling)

Tags: macroeconomics, exchange-rates

What will be the real value of the Euro/Sterling exchange rate if:

Given that:

Index of UK prices$=118$, Index of Euro-area prices$=110$, Nominal Euro/Sterling exchange rate$=1.58$ and UK marginal tax rate$=0.15$.

My attempt,
$\text{RER}=\text{NER}\cdot\frac{
{\text{Price of domestic goods}}}{\text{Price of foreign goods}}$

$$\text{RER}=1.58\cdot\frac{110}{118}=1.47$$

But the given answer is $1.69$. Why?

Comment: I think your textbook wants you to treat UK as a home country if you do that you get 1.69 since 1.58*(118/110) is approximately 1.69

Comment: But the question stated Euro/Sterling. Wouldn’t it be treating Euro is a home instead of U.K.? And why the UK marginal rate appeared in this question ?

Comment: no exchange rate can be quoted in direct or indirect way. Both are valid exchange rate quotations - in your class teacher should be clear which one you should follow see here https://www.toppr.com/guides/economics/open-economy-macroeconomics/exchange-rate/ . The marginal tax rate might be something to throw you off it’s a standard teacher tactic to include some unrelated number to test if student can determine what information is important

Comment: It's actually a multiple choice question. 

A)1.69
B)1.47
C)1.23

The given answer is A.

Comment: yes in that case still my first comment applies

Answer (score 2):

Dimensional analysis is useful here.

$$\text{RER}=1.58\frac{\text{Euro}}{\text{Sterling}}\cdot\frac{110\text{ Euro}}{118\text{ Sterling}}=1.47\frac{\text{Euro}^2}{\text{Sterling}^2}$$

where the unit of measurement is very strange indeed, since the real exchange rate should be a number without a unit of measurement. (Well, technically it is basket of British goods/basket of Euro goods.) This indicates that there is an error in the calculation above, and rereading the *logic* behind RER calculation is probably useful.

Comment: 1muflon1 seems to be correct in their assessment, since flipping the price index from a euro to sterling ratio to sterling to euro ratio would cancel out all the units.

Comment: @HHuang Indeed. My answer is just meant to provide a simple control mechanism for students to see if they have "accidentally flipped" the price ratios.